# Wolfram Matematica: set NIntegral's domain with Table

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, range, multidimensional-array, integral, wolframalpha

I would like perform an NIntegrate in Wolfram Mathematica in n-dimension, for example making the NIntegrate of the 9-dimension function:

`p=Product[(1+x[i])^((-1)^i),{i,0,9}]`

so I thought to set the range with a Table:

`t=Table[ {x[i], 1,2}, {i,0,9}]`

Unfortunately the command 
`NIntegrate[p,t]`

returns the Error:

`NIntegrate::vars: 
   Integration range specification t is not of the form {x, xmin, ..., xmax}.`

I've tested with some commands as "Extract", "Part" and so on, but nothing works.
Someone can help a niubb as me?!

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there. Some further manipulation of the integration limits is needed:

```
p = Product[(1 + x[i])^((-1)^i), {i, 0, 9}]
t = Table[{x[i], 1, 2}, {i, 0, 9}]

Integrate[p, Evaluate[Sequence @@ t]]
(*
3125/32 Log[3/2]^5
*)
```